# Подсветка ссылок при клике в chrome

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Доброго всем времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на сайте при клике по ссылкам когда открываешь с мобильного в хроме возникает такое синее выделение, заскринить не могу потому что оно возникает после клика по ссылке и до открытия элемента буквально на доли секунды. Аналогично в файрфоксе возникала рамка пунктирная, но она убралась таким кодом:

```
a, a:active, a:hover, a:link, a:visited, a:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: none;
}
```

Ну и соответственно вопрос: как отключить это ущербное мигание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте элементам `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: А почему не `transparent` вместо `rgba(0,0,0,0)`?) (просто интересно)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, да что первое в голову пришло, то и написал), можно и `transparent`, без разницы)